# Eclipse Crashed when Started

Tags: java, eclipse

The last thing I remember was changing the web browser preferences in eclipse. I had changed it to WebKit from Chrome. I was trying to test a dynamic web project, and as soon as I changed the browser and ran the application,
eclipse crashed....

It generated an error log when I restarted it, which is here-
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p6g8mitc2ywcz60/hs_err_pid4856.log

Comment: Don't paste Dropbox links here, please. You should have provided the relevant part inline with your question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik- I am unable to paste the contents of the log file, as it is too long and does no fit within the 40,000 characters limit.... Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

If -clean works then great else change the workspace and import your project again will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add a -clean parameter to your shortcut, then start eclipse and then remove the -clean parameter again.

```
"C:\Program Files(x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.exe" -clean
```

This will clean your workspace and will probably fix your problem.